# Why iOS 11 changed next view controller's viewDidLoad before viewWillDisappear

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ios11

I have two view controllers in one navigation controller. When the first one push the second one, second view controller's viewDidLoad called before first one's viewWillDisappear in iOS 11. But in iOS 10 and before, I have the opposite result. I will clean some data when first will disappear. So anyone knows why iOS changed this order? Many thanks in advance!